# Draw Larger and Smaller UIImageView size when scrolling in iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

I have an app of photo catalog on my iPhone.
This app shows three images on screen with scrollview.
I want to enlarge/shrink the image size when I am scrolling.
I want to expand the image size when the image is centered.
And draw the image smaller when scrolled away from center to right/left.
I think this behaviour needs to developed in `scrollViewDidScroll`.
Do you know how to do this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you want a Coverflow ,
iCarousel may be the best control for it

take a look  https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: Thanks for you help. But I don't have time to develop with this library and change for my code.I want to know how can I expand/reduce the Imagesize when scrolled from center posintion to left/right side.

Comment: http://www.chupamobile.com/products/details/303/iCarousel/    look at the picture, is there any type that you want?

Comment: if you want change your image just do it in scrollViewDidScroll, then calculate the position & size with  scrollView.contentOffset

Comment: Thanks for your advice.Don't you have any example?